# How did Hiro help YT out of jail?

Tags: neal-stephenson, snow-crash

In Snow Crash, Hiro Protagonist is called on by YT to help her get out of jail when she was caught in a burbclave without a permit.

How did Hiro help her out if he was in the Black Sun with David watching him have his system crash after doing Snow Crash?

The book literally jumps from Hiro in the club to YT calling Hiro and him showing up to Hiro in the club again as if he was never gone....

Or I missed something...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book isn't wholly chronological. When Hiro is in the Black Sun, he is jacked in from inside the U-Stor-It he shares with Vitally. He doesn't meet Vitally until after YT tips him off about his band, which happens at the very *end* of the sequence where he's helping her out of the Clink, after the bit about the Rat Things.

From my reads of the book, I always felt like the beginning "Deliverator" bit was added after the book was largely complete, to give a more exciting intro.

Comment: Ok, so when Hiro goes into the Metaverse to meet David, that was a couple weeks AFTER the incident with her in the jail? Feel free to explain it better to me in the chat, because I'm really confused with this part of the novel, lol.

Comment: @oghma: Correct. I'll dig up some citations when I get home tonight. There are a couple of places where the timeline is pegged quite exactly. Hiro talks about how long he's been unemployed during the bit immediately prior to the first Black Sun scene, and what's-his-name, the gargoyle references the time Hiro's spent working on the Meltdowns.

Comment: Ok, cool. If you have the time, you can probably explain a few chapters for me. I'll be in the chatroom all night so just @ me in there and I'll respond pretty quickly.

Answer (score 5):

**Hiro rescuing YT occurs the night he and YT met, 5 weeks prior to Hiro going the The Black Sun, so there is no conflict.**

The time sequence of the early portions of *Snow Crash* is:

- Chapter 1: Hiro receives a pizza with a short delivery timeline
- Chapter 2: Hiro crashes into a pool, meets YT
- Chapter 4: YT delivers the pizza
- Chapter 6: Immediately after delivery, YT is arrested.
- Chapter 10: YT calls Hiro; gets rescued, flees to Hong Kong
- Chapter 12: YT and Hiro are saved by the Rat Thing. YT and Hiro become partners, and YT tells Hiro about Vitaly

---

---

- Chapter 3: Sometime later ("a few short weeks" after he lost his job as a pizza Deliverator), Hiro lives with Vitaly. He goes to the Metaverse
- Chapter 5: In the Metaverse, Hiro heads to the Black Sun - encounters Raven
- Chapter 7: In the Black Sun, Hiro sees Juanita, remembers their past
- Chapter 8: Hiro talks with Juanita.
- Chapter 9: Da5id infected and thrown out of the Black Sun
- Chapter 11: Hiro duels in the Black Sun
- Chapter 13: Post-duel: in Reality, Hiro heads to a concert with Vitaly; in the Metaverse, Hiro meets the Librarian
- Chapter 14: Hiro is still in the library - YT is following the van with Hiro and Vitaly in reality.
- Chapter 15: Hiro at the concert (Lagos says Hiro was fired 36 days earlier).

From this point on, YT's and Hiro's chapters are mostly in synch, with Hiro learning about Sumeria, while YT gets employed by the Mafia and Mr. Ng.